# Can't create a query

Tags: vb.net, pervasive

I've googled this a lot and can't find and answer (probably because it's so rudimentary).

I'm creating a simple VB application to search for items in a pervasive database.  I've managed to connect to the database, but can't figure out how to create and execute a query.  I'm quite new to this, but here's what I have.

```
Dim idText As String
Dim myPsqlConnection As PsqlConnection = New PsqlConnection()
myPsqlConnection.ConnectionString = "ServerName=FILESERVER;ServerDSN=myDSN"
myPsqlConnection.Open()
'run query here, but I don't know how!
myPsqlConnection.Close()
```

I'm looking for a way to execute a simple 'select * from table where feild=something' kind of query, no inserts, deletes, or updates.. read only.

Comment: many things could be wrong - show your best attempt as is, it looks like you are asking for a tutorial which is far too broad

Comment: I don't even know where to begin.. that's the trouble.  is it myPsqlConnection.Query('querystring') or myPsqlConnection.runQuery('querystring') or myPsqlConnection.GoBabyGo('querystring') do I have to create some other object first?

Comment: if the question is too broad, could some tell me where I might find this information, and I'll just delete the question

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand(v=vs.110).aspx it is for OleDB (example at the bottom), but should get you pointed in the right direction

Comment: Thanks for the info, it did help, but not quite as much as the answer below.  I'm up voting your comment for your courtesy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look at [PsqlCommand and PsqlDataReader objects](http://docs.pervasive.com/products/database/psqlv11/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=adonet/objintrf.08.3.html).
A very simple VB.NET app that executes a query is:

```
Imports Pervasive.Data.SqlClient

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim conn As New PsqlConnection("ServerDSN=DEMODATA")
        Dim cmd As New PsqlCommand("select id,name from class", conn)
        conn.Open()
        Dim dr As PsqlDataReader
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While (dr.Read)
            Console.WriteLine("ID: " & dr("id").ToString() & " -- " & "Name: " & dr("name").ToString())
        End While
        dr.Close()
        conn.Close()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: That did it!  Thanks for humoring the newbie!